# Unexpected parameter handling in python Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

While creating a custom Exception class, I encountered an unexpected situation how the base
Exception class handles parameters.  Specifically, with how it sets the 'message' attribute.

When you pass more than one parameter to the `Exception.__init__()`, it does not initialize the message attribute.  For example, this works

```
>>> e = Exception('msg')
>>> e.message
'msg'
```

BUT This does NOT set the message attribute

```
>>> e = Exception('msg', 'extra')
>>> e.message
''
```

It does of course store all the parameters in the args attribute:

```
>>> e = Exception('msg', 'extra')
>>> e.args
('msg', 'extra')
```

Can anyone shed light on this? I've scoured the Exception docs, but I'm at a loss to understand why the Exception class does this. In case it matters, this is python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6f6e56bb10aa/Objects/exceptions.c#l56), Luke!

```
BaseException_init(PyBaseExceptionObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    if (!_PyArg_NoKeywords(Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name, kwds))
        return -1;

    Py_DECREF(self->args);
    self->args = args;
    Py_INCREF(self->args);

    if (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self->args) == 1) {
        Py_CLEAR(self->message);
        self->message = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(self->args, 0);
        Py_INCREF(self->message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So message is only set if the args is length 1.

The reason for this behaviour is for backwards compatibility.  `Exception.message` is [deprecated](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#transition-plan) since python 2.6, and the implementation for `BaseException.__str__` doesn't look at message at all - it only uses the args tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the code -- but I'm curious about why this behavior is true?

Comment: Thanks...I'll accept this as the correct answer (need to wait 6 minutes for SO to allow this). Do you have a reference to the deprecated statement? I'd like to read up.

Comment: See [PEP-352](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352). The `message` attribute was actually a short-lived addition to the `BaseException` class, added in 2.5 but immediately deprecated in 2.6.